# LDAP Server Communication issue for existing user

Tags: java, ldap

I wrote a java program integrated with LDAP. When an existing user tries to login with their AD credentials, am I getting the following error, but it works fine for the new users created in AD. What can be the problem?

> javax.naming.PartialResultException [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: CBSL.AD.389 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: CBSL.AD]]

Comment: Your app can't find host name `CBSL.AD`, use `ping CBSL.AD` or other network command like `nslookup CBSL.AD`, to check host.

Comment: what is `CBSL.AD.389` ? `CBSL.AD:389` or `CBSL.AD.389`

Comment: @life888888 CBSL.AD is domain and 389 is LDAP port. when I create a new user in AD., they can successfully login. this issue is raised with existing users.